# circumventing ui-dialog .dialog() conflict with mobile .dialog()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am one of those that is trying to use both jquery-ui and jqm. Things are working except when I try to use the jquery-ui dialog.

The call to

```
$('#tag').dialog(options)
```

goes to jquery mobile's dialog, when I include jquery-mobile.js. I am interested in using the ui-dialog and NOT jquery mobile dialog.

After a little research, I see that ui.dialog is getting installed as $['ui']['dialog] and I am wondering if there is a way to call it from there directly to circumvent the call to .dialog() getting passed to mobile's dialog(). So do something like :

```
var dialogInstance = $['ui]['dialog']({Options...}, tag);
```

Where tag is $('#tag'). I tried to do this and got the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_createWidget'
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong. Before I spend more time, looking for expert advice.

Sorry, new to jquery ui/mobile. Any help is much appreciated !!

Comment: Flipping the order of jquery mobile.js and ui.js did the trick for me for now. So jquery-ui's dialog is loaded after mobile's and I am able to get this work... (The styles for mobile are little bit messed up (only buttons seem to be).